# unable to run requirements.txt file while building docker image

Tags: python, pip, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image which includes a requirements.txt file, but while running the built its failing to install the dependencies.

here is the docker file content:
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:flask

```
> # copy over our requirements.txt file COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
> 
> # upgrade pip and install required python packages RUN apt-get update pip install -U pip RUN apt-get update pip install -r
> /tmp/requirements.txt
> 
> # copy over our app code COPY ./app /app
```

requirements.txt:

```
Flask==0.12.2
pyfiglet==0.7.5
```

here is the error that is coming up:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb04e93a950>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pip/
```

but when i am running the requirements as `pip install requirements.txt`, then its working fine.

Am i doing anything wrong? can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

my firewall was blocking the connection. it works fine now.